# How to separate points and find corners of the points in python based on their distance

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, distance, point

I have some points in the 3d space (`x`, `y` and `z`). These point sets are stored as arrays in lists. I copied a simplified example having two point sets:

```
all_points=[[np.array([[6.8,1.,0.1], [6.8,3.,0.1], [6.8,6.,0.1],\
                       [5.8,1.,1.1], [5.8,3.,1.1], [5.8,6.,1.1],\
                       [4.8,1.,2.], [4.8,3.,2.], [4.8,6.,2.],\
                       [3.8,1.,3.], [3.8,3.,3.], [3.8,6.,3.],\
                       [2.8,1.,4.1], [2.8,3.,4.1], [2.8,6.,4.1]]),\
             np.array([[5.,1.,2.], [5.,3.,2.], [5.,6.,2.],[6.,1.,1.2],\
                       [4.,1.,3.], [4.,3.,3.], [4.,6.,3.],[5.5,3.,1.5],\
                       [6.,1.,3.], [6.,3.,3.], [6.,6.,3.],\
                       [7.,1.,4.], [7.,3.,4.], [7.,6.,4.],\
                       [3.,1.,4.], [3.,3.,4.], [3.,6.,4.]])]]
```

My point sets are normal or abnormal. They are normal if when I sort them based on their `z`, the `x` value will be only increasing or decreasing. Blue dots in my fig cleary show the normal type. But black squares show an abnormal point set. These two sets are linked because some points of the abnormal set are close to the normal one. Minimum and maximum of `y` value in both normal and abnormal sets is fixed (`1` and `6` in my example). In normal set, I simply want four corners of them (shown by green arrows in my fig). This code gives me four corners:

```
four_corners=[]
for points in all_points:
    for sub_points in points:
        sorted_sub=np.sort(sub_points.view('i8,i8,i8'), order=['f2', 'f1'], axis=0).view('float')
        le_st=sorted_sub[np.where(sorted_sub[:,2] == sorted_sub[0,2])]
        le_st=len(le_st)
        le_en=sorted_sub[np.where(sorted_sub[:,2] == sorted_sub[-1,2])]
        le_en=len(le_en)
        cor=np.array([sorted_sub[0,:], sorted_sub[int((le_st-1)),:], sorted_sub[-1,:], sorted_sub[-le_en,:]])
        four_corners.append(cor)
```

Abnormal point sets can be devided into two groups: a group that is close to normal point sets and another one is far from them. A threshold can separate them. I tried the following code to seperate them (I should transfer my normal and abnormal arrays automatically here, but I have written them manually):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy_indexed as npi
threshold=0.5
close_points=abnormal[np.where(np.min(distance.cdist(abnormal, normal),axis=0)<threshold)[0],:]
far_points= npi.difference(abnormal, close_points)
```

After separation, I want two points from `far_points` and two point from `close_points`. In `far_points` I want two point that have the highest `z` values and have min of `y` (`1`) and max of `y` (`6`). These two points are shown by yellow arrows in my fig and are:

```
[[7.,1.,4.], [7.,6.,4.]]
```

In `close_points` I want the points that their `y` value is again `min` and `max` (`1` and `6`). I name them `y_min` and `y_max` subgroups and from each subgroup, I want the point that the least `z` value. In my data they are and are shown by red arrows:

```
[[6.,1.,1.2],[5.,6.,2.]]
```

Finally, I want to find two point of the normal point sets that are closest to theese two point of `close_points` of the abnormal group. They are:

```
[[5.8,1.,1.1], [4.8,6.,2.]]
```

So, I want a method to firstly distiguish which array is normal and which is abnormal. Then find four simple corners of my normal sets and explained four explained points of abnormal sets. the method should be also able to ditinguish which normal set is connected to which abnormal ones. I may have one normal sets and two or three linked abnormal sets or maybe two normals and one abnormal which is connected to a normal set. I do appreciate any help for doing what I want in python.
[image]